# Why is Facebook preventing me from adding links to my wall posts?

Tags: facebook, links, facebook-timeline

Recently when I have tried adding links to wall posts on Facebook I have gotten the following warning:

> The privacy settings for this attachment prevent you from posting it to this Timeline.

What is causing this warning and is it possible to change the settings to allow link posting?

Comment: Immediate, but not permanent fix - [at this FB Support Thread](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=4624046321981)

Comment: @NicholasV. thanks for the link.  I did see that but it only indicates a crude work-around and does not provide any insight into why this is happening.

Comment: True, will continue looking.

Answer (score 4):

As per this [Facebook Community Help Post](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=4624046321981):

Click "Add Photo/Video", and then click back to "Write Post" and it will link fine!!!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of *why* it's doing this.